# How to compare two ranked lists of genes with ranking values?

Tags: similarities, genetics, ranks

I have 80 independent sets of genes with 6000 genes in each. Gene expression values are ranked and scaled from 0 to 1. So, a set looks like this:

Gene1 1

Gene2 0.98

Gene3 0.85

...

Gene5998 0.002

Gene5999 0.0015

Gene6000 0.00001

Each set has 6000 of the same genes, but of course, the expression values are different in each set. However, I should have several couples of sets that are very similar. By similar, I mean that the majority of genes should have similar values in two sets. What will be the best way to find those similar sets? And how to show that similarity?

One way that I was thinking is to take set A and set B, remove all genes with expression lower than some threshold (like 0.01) in both sets, and find Jaccard similarity between gene sets. But it is hard to set a threshold in this case.

More details as requested:
Those 80 gene sets were obtained from two different datasets. The goal is to see if some of the 40 gene sets from dataset 1 are similar to some of the 40 sets from dataset 2.

Comment: *"However, I should have several couples of sets that are very similar"* There are so many different ways to compare the distance between two numeric vectors. What is the context that helps to make decisions about the different ways? This sounds more like a question that requires in the first place domain knowledge rather than knowledge about statistics. Could you tell more about the purpose of finding the couples. Why are you looking for these couples?

Comment: Those 80 gene sets were obtained from two different datasets. The goal is to see if some of the 40 gene sets from dataset 1 are similar to some of the 40 sets from dataset 2.

Comment: What is important about similarity? What makes two sets of gene expression data similar?

Comment: I think sets will be considered similar if the genes with higher ranks in set A and set B are similar. But there is no specific threshold for "higher rank". That is why I wonder if we can at least somehow show that shows that sets A and B are more similar than sets A and C.

Comment: You speak about 'similar' but we are not molecular biologists here. Are 0.9 and 0.8 more or less similar than 0.4 and 0.5 are similar? What is the basis of the comparison? Why is there a difference in importance of higher ranks. How do you determine the performance of your analysis? Is it supposed to detect duplicate measurements from an identical organism or identify close relatives? Is there statistical variation in the measurements and if, then how does it look like? Do the gene id's matter, for instance are there blocks whose expressions correlate or is it all independent? Etcetera.

Comment: We can look at those values as importance scores from 0 to 1. These are the results of a novel gene grouping method based on mutual information, so we rely on those scaled scores for now. In this case, 0.9 vs 0.8 and 0.4 vs 0.5 will have the same similarity. I don't think the biological aspect really matters at this point, because the values are not exactly expression values. Could you please direct me to some commonly used methods to compare two numeric vectors that you mentioned earlier? Maybe I will be able to figure out if it is applicable to my data. Thank you.

Comment: *"Could you please direct me to some commonly used methods to compare two numeric vectors"* You could think about [Euclidian distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) or [Manhattan distance](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry). Whether it is relevant we can not know without background of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but if you do not have an answer you could try like the Rank-Based Overlap described here: "A Similarity Measure for Indefinite Rankings" (Webber, Moffat, Zobol, 2010). Some features:

- it assigns higher weights to the higher ranked genes
- if the lists are disjoint (for example, you use your 0.01 cutoff so that the lists
  contain potentially different genes), this is also allowed

If you only have the two lists, it may be hard to interpret the size of the value, but you could probably get a p-value for example by permutations of one of the lists.